# JMockit, how to mock a method that return Exception, not throw Exception

Tags: exception, jmockit

I need to mock an object with a property holding exception. When I try to mock

```
new Expectations() {{
  instance.getError();
  result = new Exception("");
}};
```

JMockIt throw this exception instead of return this exception.

Is there anyway I can return an Exception using mock?

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question:

Use
`returns(new Exception(""), null);`

Comment: Or, use a MockUp